# How to Split the success message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I am showing this **Success Message** in **MVC**.

TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "File uploaded successfully.These invalid Companies '" + CompanyNames + "' are not saved as the company do not exist.\n Please create company  before you create cost centres".

**Its shows like this.**

File uploaded successfully.These invalid Companies xxx,yyy are not saved as the company do not exist.\n Please create company  before you create cost centres.

**But i want like this.**

File uploaded successfully.
These invalid Companies xxx,yyy are not saved as the company do not exist.
Please create company  before you create cost centres.

How to split the message into new line.  \n is not working.

Comment: You can use `Environment.NewLine` to add a line break, but I suspect you mean its not showing line breaks in the view. Use `.css` to style the element to have `white-space: pre;` which will display linebeaks in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add html tags to your string and use html.Raw helper like following:

controller

```
TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "<div>File uploaded successfully.</div><div>These invalid Companies '" + ...
```

view

```
@Html.Raw(TempData["SuccessMessage"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br />` to break line

```
TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "File uploaded successfully.<br />These invalid Companies xxx,yyy are not saved as the company do not exist.<br />Please create company before you create cost centres.";
```

In View

```
@Html.Raw(@TempData["SuccessMessage"])
```

[Check this Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7Wltd)

Comment: If it is helpful then vote up and accept it as answered!